# override html inline background-color with css hover

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, I need to change a table background-color, I can only change the css. I want a hover on a table tr but some of the table td have an inline bg-color and I can't get a hover over it. !important doesn't work. Here is my problem.

CSS

```css
table{
border: 1px solid black;
}

table tr:hover{
background-color: pink !important;
}
```

```html
HTML
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:green;">test1</td>
        <td>test2</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style is Incorrect, In the CSS you try to change the `tr` background, not the `td`.

Replace the css by this and it works fine if you want change all the hover line in pink :

```
table tr:hover td{
    background-color: pink !important;
}
```

Replace the css by this and it works fine if you want change the hover `td` in pink :

```
table td:hover{
    background-color: pink !important;
}
```

Comment: I want the hole tr line change bg-color when you hover, not only the td

Answer (score 4):

Adding rules for td fixed your problem

```
table tr:hover td
```

```css
table{
border: 1px solid black;
}

table tr:hover,
table tr:hover td {
background-color: pink !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:green;">test1</td>
        <td>test2</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```